# Tensorflow 1.9 Bazel build error with Cuda on Windows

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to compile a sample program which uses Tensorflow core, with CUDA support on Windows 10 64bit via Bazel on the following environments:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- CUDA Toolkit 9.0
- CUDNN 9.0
- Tensorflow 1.9
- Bazel 0.16

I went through the configure.py successfully, I added the CUDA and the CUDNN location.

This is my Bazel BUILD file:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "mnistpredict.dll",
  srcs = ["mnist.cc", "MNIST.h"],
  deps = [
      "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
  ],
  linkshared=1
)
```

I try to compile with this command: 
bazel build //tensorflow/loadgraph:mnistpredict.dll

> ERROR:
>   C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/tensorflow/loadgraph/BUILD:1:1:
>   error loading package 'tensorflow/core': Encountered error while
>   reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package
>   '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl",
>   line 1166
>                   _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl",
>   line 995, in _create_local_cuda_repository
>                   _get_cuda_config(repository_ctx)
>           File "C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl",
>   line 750, in _get_cuda_config
>                   _cudnn_version(repository_ctx, cudnn_install_base..., ...)
>           File "C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl",
>   line 466, in _cudnn_version
>                   find_cuda_define(repository_ctx, cudnn_header_dir, "c...", ...)
>           File "C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl",
>   line 422, in find_cuda_define
>                   auto_configure_fail(("Error reading %s: %s" % (str(h...)))
>           File "C:/users/laci/downloads/tensorflow-1.9.0/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl",
>   line 210, in auto_configure_fail
>                   fail(("\n%sCuda Configuration Error:%...)))
>
> Cuda Configuration Error: Error reading
>   C:/Users/laci/Downloads/cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.1/cuda/include/cudnn.h:
>   java.io.IOException: ERROR:
>   src/main/native/windows/processes-jni.cc(239): CreateProcessW("grep"
>   --color=never -A1 -E "#define CUDNN_MAJOR" C:/Users/laci/Downloads/cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.1/cuda/include/cudnn.h):
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> and referenced by '//tensorflow/loadgraph:mnistpredict.dll' ERROR:
>   Analysis of target '//tensorflow/loadgraph:mnistpredict.dll' failed;
>   build aborted: Analysis failed INFO: Elapsed time: 1.612s INFO: 0
>   processes. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages
>   loaded)
>       currently loading: tensorflow/core

When I try it without CUDA support, I can compile it successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was looking for grep.exe under %PATH% but failed.  Either adding Git\bin to %PATH% or install grep for Windows will do the trick.

It had taken me several days to finally build a tensorflow-gpu 1.10 whl on Windows 7 64 bit with bazel + msys2.